# Can a Kafka Streams StateStore be used outwith the Kafka Streams API?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I'm writing an application that uses the Kafka Producer API to publish messages.

My code has some key value metadata that I need to store in a fault tolerant manner. I could implement this myself using compacted topics with Kafka. However, Kafka Streams `StateStore` provides exactly this functionality.

Is it possible to create and use a `StateStore` out-with a Kafka Streams processor topology?

Comment: No, that is not possible.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax thanks for that. Please add an answer and I can accept. Are there any plans for supporting this (or something similar) in the future?

Comment: There are no plans. StateStores are a concept coupled to Kafka Streams API -- IMHO, it does not make sense to add Stores to simple consumer or producer.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax do you not think a fault tolerant Map backed by a compacted topic is a reasonable idea though? I can't be the only person with this use case. And I don't want to introduce another piece of technology into my setup to provide this if I can avoid it.

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable idea, but still I doubt it should be part of producer of consumer.

Comment: Any updates to this? Seems like I need to query the state store while processing a stream inside the processor topology. Any suggestions/pointers appreciated.

Comment: @NikhilSahu in the end I created my own class where I have a HashMap that is populated from a Kafka topic on startup. Any changes are then propagated via standard producers and consumers.